# Unit tests mock an interface from struct property

Tags: go

I want to mock a property from a struct that uses an interface so I don't get a nil pointer when the function arrives at that point.

This is the code:

```
type Server struct{
    parser: Parser
}

type Parser interface{
    SetProvider(p *Provider)
}

func (s *Server) doSomething(){
    s.anotherAction()
    // ...
    // here it crashes because I haven't assigned anything to parser in serverMock
    s.parser.SetProvider(&Provider{
        name: "foo"
    })
}
```

And this the test code:

```
var serverMock = &Server{
    parser:
}

// mock SetProvider
func (s *Server) SetProvider(p *Provider) {
    // some action
}


TestMyCustomTest(){
    res, err := serverMock.doSomething()
    expected := struct{
        hobby: "code",
    }
    assert.Equal(t, &expected, res)
}
```

As you see I haven't assigned anything to `parser:` from `var serverMock` because I still don't know what should I do to make it work. I cannot assign a mockInterface to that parser field because it'll tell me that the original Server struct requires the `Parser` interface not a mock one and I think I need the `&Server` pointer for `var serverMock = &Server` because it's using other actions like `s.anotherAction()`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test in `TestMyCustomTest`? You trying to test `Server`'s `doSomething` method, right?

Comment: "I cannot assign a mockInterface to that parser field because it'll tell me that the original Server struct requires the Parser interface" - this sounds like you're doing something odd. A mock is a *concrete implementation* which satisfies the interface you're mocking. A "mock interface" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin I edited my answer. It doesn't matter the assert.Equal it's just an example, the whole point is that `serverMock.doSomething()` crashes because it cannot use the SetProvider from it...

Comment: @Adrian ok then how can I make it not crash when it reaches the `s.parser.SetProvider` ?

Comment: Fill the `parser` field with a mock *implementation* of the correct interface.

Comment: your code has so many errors in it, it's actually tricky to work out what you're trying to do, and what exactly you're testing. Just generate mocks using something like `mockgen`. Unit tests shouldn't be covering setter behaviours of dependencies, just the code of the package/type you're actually testing

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your intention correctly, you want to test `Server`'s `doSomething` method and it depends on `Parser.SetProvider` method. So, what you want, instead of mocking `Server`, is to create mock struct that satisfies `Parser` interface and create `Server` instance that uses it. Here is example of such test:

```golang
type mockParser struct {
    // You can add field here
}

// mockParser implements SetProvider(p *Provider) method so that it satisfies Parser interface
func (parser *mockParser) SetProvider(provider *Provider) {
    // You can do something here
}

TestMyCustomTest(t *testing.T){
    parser := mockParser{}
    srv := &Server{parser: &parser}

    // write your test

    assert.Equal(t, ...)
}
```

Comment: @alex Updated answer, was passing mockParser by value

Comment: why a pointer it's expecting an interface of course it doesn't work: Cannot use '&parser' (type *mockParser) as type Parser

Comment: @alex Because `*mockParser` actually implements interface `Parser`. regarding your error, i can't help you without seeing actual code that you're trying to run. Can you provide minimal reproducible example?